# Python Inner For Loop Not Going To Else Statment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#variable declarations
array_value = str
#declares the two dimensional array as a string
Zoo_Animal = [["", ""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""]]
#loading the array
for row in range(0,6,1):
    for column in range(0,1,1):
        #determining the input statement
        if column == 0:
            array_value = input("Enter the name of a Zoo animal: ")
        else:
            array_value = input("Enter where the animal came from: ")
        #end if
          #adding the input value to the array
        Zoo_Animal[row][column] = array_value
    #end For
#end For
print(Zoo_Animal)
```

Just wondering for my code why isn't it ever going to the 11th line, I thought for loops auto counted, or do I need to somehow reset the counter?

Comment: the `for loop` for `column` has only one variable and it is zero. here is you loop `for column in range(0,1,1):` change this line into `for column in range(0,2):`

Comment: wow, such an easy fix aha I thought 0 technically counted as 1 for example 0=1 1=2 etc.

Comment: To debug this yourself you could print the value of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor adjustment, note that the range(0,1) function only creates a iterator with one value being 0. So it counts up until (but not included) 1.

```
#variable declarations
array_value = str
#declares the two dimensional array as a string
Zoo_Animal = [["", ""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""], ["",""]]
#loading the array
for row in range(0,6,1):
    for column in range(0,2):
        #determining the input statement
        if column == 0:
            array_value = input("Enter the name of a Zoo animal: ")
        else:
            array_value = input("Enter where the animal came from: ")
        #end if
          #adding the input value to the array
        Zoo_Animal[row][column] = array_value
    #end For
#end For
print(Zoo_Animal)
```